# Best circuit to play music in car, using ISO 10487

Tags: automotive, lm386, music

instead of using a radio, I want to install a Raspberry Pi 3 with my own features in the 2Din Slot, so I have to make my own circuit to play audio. I tried with the following modules based in LM386 pic:

[image]

It doesn't work bad at all, but neither good enough, the max volume is not as high as I would like it to be, the sound is not clear, starts to crackle if I increase it, and the bass level is so bad.

Should I try with my own LM386 circuit where I select my own resistor and capacitors till I get the sound I want? should I look for another circuit? another device? maybe something like an equalizer? I would like it to be small enough and as customizable as possible. Also, high bass is one of my priorities.

Voltage is 12.6v
Speakers resistance is 4ohms

Comment: Have you looked at the datasheet of LM386? Look the "Distortion vs Output Power" graph. See how the curve dramatically raises from 0.2Watts? LM386 is totally unsuitable for this usage.

Comment: uh :/ so what pic should I look for?

Comment: "pic"? What does that mean? Picture? Anyway, it seems you prefer premade modules. Look for some class-D amp modules that advertise 2x 20 watts or something like that. There are tons of those on the internet. Note that you could use a class AB amp (or make one yourself), but I'm afraid the cooling will become a problem in the car DIN slot.

Comment: it means programmable integrated circuit :D I just want to get the better result and I don't mind to build it by myself, thanks.

Comment: LM386 is not programmable. No, please, use the right terms. You just meant "IC". And in full-capitals, it's better, since we can then understand it's an acronym (yes, I can be worse than Goebbels sometimes).

Comment: nah, you re right, my bad :)

Comment: Various sorts of class D amps are used for this, you might want >100W. Have a look at https://github.com/ambientsound/caracas

Comment: Goebbels wasn't that bad LOL.

Comment: Last advice: given the bad things that can happen on the battery voltage, you'd likely want to put some [protection](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/17108/protection-against-automotive-power-supply-hazards?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LM386 power amplifiers are just too puny to overcome high ambient noise level inside a car. The cracking you describe could have two causes: power amplifier clipping, or speaker overload. Considering the weak driver (LM386), amplifier clipping likely causes distortion, and limits power output.
You certainly need a more powerful amplifier. Some considerations for you before choosing a solution:
*What net speaker resistance will the amplifier drive? (8 ohms? 4 ohms?...)*
*From what DC voltage source will the amplifier be powered? (12.6v? custom?)*

Your open-ended sound-level spec ("not as high as I would like it to be", "high bass is one of my priorities") is too subjective. It is possible that a bridged amplifier powered from the 12.6v car source will satisfy, if it drives a 4-ohm speaker load.
[image: Bridged one-channel amplifier] At maximum volume (where clipping begins), conversation with an adjacent companion will be very difficult. If you need more volume, a higher DC supply voltage than 12.6v would be required. I am assuming old-school Class AB linear amplifier technology, similar to the low-power LM386.

Comment: I updated my question, 12.6v and 8ohms (I guess)

Comment: Hm, I'm looking for that TDA2005M, I got some doubts... do I need one IC per channel (L and R), right? so I connect R output with both rear and front R in series? At least thats how I did with the module shown in my picture. Well, by now I will look for the datasheet.

Comment: @McKernel , Yes, one IC for LEFT, another IC for RIGHT. I would connect *Rfront & Rrear* in parallel, not series. (*Lfront parallel Lrear*). Be careful to phase properly for good bass. Consider too, **dim** suggestion of Class D bridged amps for their better efficiency, less heatsinking required. You'll need considerable heatsink for those two TDA2005's.

Comment: Alright, at first I tried in parallel, but for some reason it didn't gave me any good result at all, I tried in series and worked much better :/

Comment: @McKernel , speakers parallel with LM386? Those can't put out enough current into parallel speakers. Lots of current drive should allow parallel speakers to sound loud.